# Как вызвать значение метода из другого метода

Tags: c#, .net

Программа рассчитывает, является ли год високосным или нет. Мне нужно вызвать значение bool метода IsLeapYear, и если значение true - написать високосный год, если значение false - написать не високосный год. Буду признателен за любой совет.

```
 class Program
    {
           public static void Main(string[] args)
           {
                       
                 Console.WriteLine(IsLeapYear(2014));
                 Console.WriteLine(IsLeapYear(1999));
                 Console.WriteLine(IsLeapYear(8992));
                 Console.WriteLine(IsLeapYear(1));
                 Console.WriteLine(IsLeapYear(14));
                 Console.WriteLine(IsLeapYear(400));
                 Console.WriteLine(IsLeapYear(600));
                 Console.WriteLine(IsLeapYear(3200));
                 FinalTesting(bool FinalTesting()); // I don't know what arguments do i need to type
                
            }
                
                public static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
                
                {
                
                return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
                
                }
                
                public static void FinalTesting(bool IsLeapYear) //also idk
                
                {
                    if (IsLeapYear == true) { // I don't know what should i type here too
                        Console.WriteLine("leap year");
                    } else Console.WriteLine("common year");
                }
          
    }
```

Comment: Может человеку надо получить ответ именно на английском языке

Comment: @RomanIeromenko, тогда он может задать вопрос на [английской версии сайта](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените Ваш метод `Main` следующим образом:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{    
     bool isLeap = IsLeapYear(2014);
     FinalTesting(isLeap);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы мой спаситель!